# Test for autocorrelation on a number of stock returns

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I would like to conduct a test for autocorrelation (say Durbin Watson) on a dataset of stock returns. In particular, I have a dataset with quarterly stock returns, so 1 observation for each quarter, which represents the 1 day stock price return after the earnings announcement in that quarter. A min example looks like this for 2 stocks and 3 quarters:

```
data = [{'date': '3/22/18', 'return': 1},{'date': '3/22/18', 'return': 1}, 
{'date': '6/22/18', 'return': 3},{'date': '6/22/18', 'return': 3},
{'date': '9/22/18', 'return': 2},{'date': '9/22/18', 'return': 2}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['s1', 's2','s1','s2','s1','s2'])

        date  return
 s1  3/22/18       1
 s2  3/22/18       1
 s1  6/22/18       3
 s2  6/22/18       3
 s1  9/22/18       2
 s2  9/22/18       2
```

Since I have a large number of stocks, I was thinking it might make sense to perform the test individually for each stock, and then have an array of DW test statistics associated with each stock. Say something like this:

```
  s1 0.453
  s2 1.593
  s3 3.453
```

I was thinking to use:

statsmodels.stats.stattools.durbin_watson(resids, axis=0)

But I am not quite sure how to proceed to obtain that array as described above. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to use the DW test by group is as follows.
I am reusing your data generation process, adding series as a column, doing groupby and applying the test directly

```
data = [{'date': '3/22/18', 'return': 1},{'date': '3/22/18', 'return': 1}, 
{'date': '9/22/18', 'return': 3.0},{'date': '9/22/18', 'return': 3},
{'date': '6/22/18', 'return': 2},{'date': '6/22/18', 'return': 2}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['s1', 's2','s1','s2','s1','s2'])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.groupby('index')['return'].apply(lambda x: 
statsmodels.stats.stattools.durbin_watson(x, axis=0))
```

[image]